# open gles 2 shader performance

Tags: android, opengl-es

Im making a game in android but the colors are too shiny and i cant change the sprites so i decided to implement a shader:

```
const char* fETCShader = "\
uniform mediump sampler2D sTexture 
uniform mediump sampler2D sTexture_alpha 
\
varying mediump vec4 vColor 
varying mediump vec2 vTexCoord 
uniform lowp mat4 cCorrection 
\
void main()\
{\
    lowp vec4 color = vec4(texture2D(sTexture, vTexCoord).rgb, texture2D(sTexture_alpha, vTexCoord).r) * vColor 
    gl_FragColor = cCorrection * color 
}"
```

but the fps drops dramatically (like 20 )

does anyone know if exist a less expensive operation to do this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using 2 textures with 3 and 1 channels respectively, just make a single 4 channel RGBA texture, so that you only have to do 1 texture fetch.

Fragment shaders on phones very quickly become a bottleneck. Always try to minimize the amount of work your frag shaders have to do.

Your shader will look something like this:

```
const char* fETCShader = "\
uniform mediump sampler2D sTexture 
uniform mediump sampler2D sTexture_alpha 
\
varying mediump vec4 vColor 
varying mediump vec2 vTexCoord 
uniform lowp mat4 cCorrection 
\
void main()\
{\
    gl_FragColor = cCorrection * texture2D(sTexture, vTexCoord) * vColor; 
}"
```

Comment: we are using ETC texture format this format only support RGB channels, so we think we need forcibly an extra texture to save the alpha channel and create vector RGBA as shown in the Shader.

Comment: ETC2 supports RGBA, see if you can get that working. Otherwise you can try a few tricks like a vertex attribute for alpha values or just don't use ETC compression. If you're cramped for memory, try lowering the size of the textures or streaming textures in and out when they need to be used.

Comment: Hello! Can you elaborate a bit on "vertex attribute for alpha values"? Does this mean using a sampler2D in vertex shader and somehow writing results to a varying to be later used in a fragment shader?

Comment: Nope, like `attribute mediump float alpha` in the vertex shader, and an equivalent `varying` in the fragment shader. You'd send an alpha value per-vertex with your positions and texcoords.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not change the sprites exactly once, when they're first loaded, then use whatever mechanism you were using before? Failing that, at least combine the two textures into one.